# Linux executable fails with "File not found" even though the file is there and in PATH

Tags: linux, executable, dynamic-linking, wine

I want to launch the `wine` executable (Version 2.12), but I get the following error (`$`=shell prompt):

```
$ wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
$ /usr/bin/wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ./wine
bash: ./wine: No such file or directory
```

However, the file is there:

```
$ which wine
/usr/bin/wine
```

The executable definitely is there and no dead symlink:

```
$ stat /usr/bin/wine
  File: /usr/bin/wine
  Size: 9712            Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 415789      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-07-13 13:53:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2017-07-08 03:42:45.000000000 +0200
Change: 2017-07-13 13:53:00.817346043 +0200
 Birth: -
```

It is a 32-bit ELF:

```
$ file /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/wine: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, 
BuildID[sha1]=eaf6de433d8196e746c95d352e0258fe2b65ae24, stripped
```

I can get the dynamic section of the executable:

```
$ readelf -d /usr/bin/wine
Dynamic section at offset 0x1efc contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libwine.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000001d (RUNPATH)                    Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib32]
 0x0000000c (INIT)                       0x7c000854
 0x0000000d (FINI)                       0x7c000e54
 [more addresses without file names]
```

However, I cannot list the shared object dependencies using `ldd`:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/ldd: line 117: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

`strace` shows:

```
execve("/usr/bin/wine", ["wine"], 0x7fff20dc8730 /* 66 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
getpid()                                = 23783
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

**Edited to add suggestion by @jww**: The problem appears to happen before dynamically linked libraries are requested, because no `ld` debug messages are generated:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=all wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

Even when only printing the possible values of `LD_DEBUG`, the error occurs instead

```
$ LD_DEBUG=help wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

**Edited to add suggestion of @Raman Sailopal:** The problem seems to lie within the executable, as copying the contents of `/usr/bin/wine` to another already created file produces the same error

```
root:bin # cp cat testcmd    

root:bin # testcmd --help
Usage: testcmd [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Concatenate FILE(s) to standard output.
[rest of cat help page]

root:bin # dd if=wine of=testcmd  
18+1 records in
18+1 records out
9712 bytes (9.7 kB, 9.5 KiB) copied, 0.000404061 s, 24.0 MB/s

root:bin # testcmd
bash: /usr/bin/testcmd: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem or what can I do to find out which file or directory is missing?

---

`uname -a`:

```
Linux laptop 4.11.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 28 10:40:17 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: does ./wine in /usr/bin work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it gives the same error. Question edited.

Comment: I think this indicates the problem: ***`Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib32]`*** and ***`x86_64 GNU/Linux`***. Does Arch do multilib? If so, are the packages installed?

Comment: Arch is multilib-capable. Multilib repository is enabled in `/etc/pacman.conf`. All dependencies of the `wine` package are installed. However, reinstalling them just to make sure...

Comment: Do you have selinux running in enforced mode?

Comment: No, no SELinux is installed.

Comment: @jww: It is a 32-bit executable on 64-bit Arch. I think that's usual for wine. I am not aware of any problems running a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system (question edited)?

Comment: Well, maybe your next step is enable loader debugging. There's a few questions to choose from: [ld loader debugging site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=ld+loader+debugging+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and [ld environmental variables linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=ld+environmental+variables+linux) and the [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) man page. The `ld.so` man page documents envars like `LD_DEBUG`. I don't know which one to recommend because I've never needed it.

Comment: Get an executable that currently works fine and copy it to another command i.e. testcommand. Then "dd if=/usr/bin/wine of=/usr/bin/testcommand" Run /usr/bin/testcommand and see if you have the same issue. This will decipher whether it is a problem with the actual file or the permissions on the file

Comment: Thank you very much, @jww. The execution seems to fail before linking or at least before debug messages can be printed. Question edited

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @RamanSailopal. The problem seems to be related to the executable content, rather than to the file system, as the error "travels" with the copied executable content. Question edited.

Comment: Try `LD_DEBUG=files /usr/bin/wine` or `LD_DEBUG=all /usr/bin/wine`. Help is supposed to print the help message.

Comment: I did that. It is written just above the section with `LD_DEBUG=help`

Comment: I think you are better off just uninstalling and re-install Wine.

Comment: Is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` present on your system? All symptoms point to it being missing, just checking.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, you were right. In fact, the whole directory `/lib` was missing :-)

Comment: @n.m. - Forgive my ignorance... How did you determine it was `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`?

Comment: Experience ;) when you try to run an executable and get a "file not found" error while the file is obviously right here, it's the interpreter missing. Your `file` command shows what interpreter is set for this executable.

Comment: @n.m You have provided the real answer to the question what was the cause of the error. Post it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This:

```
$ file /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/wine: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, 
BuildID[sha1]=eaf6de433d8196e746c95d352e0258fe2b65ae24, stripped
```

Combined with this:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/ldd: line 117: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

Strongly suggests that the system does not have the `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` ELF interpreter.  That is, this 64-bit system does not have any 32-bit compatibility libraries installed. Thus, @user1334609's answer is essentially correct.

Comment: Is anyone going to talk about the misleading error message?

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to run 32-bit application on a 64 bit operating system, so you need to install 32-bit compatibility libraries (glibc in particular) before this can work.

Comment: Please clarify how your solution resolve the case and answer the question

Comment: What Romeo said; you would run apt-get on an arch-linux system, instead of pacman? And how would compression libraries and ncurses help them?

Answer (score 5):

FYI, I ran into this same issue running in an alpine-based docker image. The executable was a 64-bit ELF, and the alpine image was 64-bit, and the executable worked in a different container. So presumably the trimmed alpine libraries were not compatible with my executable. The [node.js Docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) notes:

> The main caveat *[to running in the Alpine-based container]* is that it does use [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) instead of [glibc and friends](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html), so certain software might run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements. However, most software doesn't have an issue with this, so this variant is usually a very safe choice. See [this Hacker News comment thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10782897) for more discussion of the issues that might arise and some pro/con comparisons of using Alpine-based images.

My solution was to use a different (e.g. Debian Jessie-based) container image.

Comment: Thanks for connecting this originally sysadmin problem to the "new" world of containers!

Answer (score 4):

OK, I was busy for the last eight hours to get my system up and running again after CPU overheating shut-down. On reboot it became apparent that it was so screwed up that even the fall-back console of initrd didn't recognize my keyboard anymore. It is a mystery for me how the system managed to stay operative for so long, while I was trying to implement the countless suggestions by you (thank you a lot!!)

Problem on reboot:

```
Warning: /lib/modules/4.11.3-1-ARCH/modules.devname not found - ignoring
ERROR: device 'UUID=...' not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: Unable to find root device 'UUID=...'.
You are being dropped to a recovery shell
Type 'exit' to try and continue booting
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
```

and no keyboard working afterwards :-)

The Problem was: An update replaced the symlink `/lib -> /usr/lib` with a directory. So that meant all libraries and kernel modules, which are expected to be in `/lib` were missing :-)

So I recreated the symlink and reinstalled the base system from a live CD.

Now that I have internet again, I also found [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.de/viewtopic.php?id=26307)

I also used the package manager of my bricked on-disk installation (called `pacman`) from the live CD to reinstall all the packages of the [base group](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/i686/base/) (maybe only the kernel, so package `linux` would have been enough, I don't know)

To accomplish that, mount the main partition of the bricked installation to the `/mnt` directory of the live CD system and use `chroot` to make `pacman` think `/mnt` is `/` (insert your bricked system's main partition for `sdXXX`)

```
mount /dev/sdXXX /mnt
# Recreate the /lib -> usr/lib symlink
ln -s usr/lib /lib  
# Mount essential system folders also to the respective subfolders of /mnt
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
# Fake /mnt to be /, so that pacman installs the packages to the correct  places
chroot /mnt
# Reinstall the Arch Linux base system
pacman -Sy base
```

For the record: create a relative symlink, so `ln -s usr/lib /mnt/lib` and not `ln -s /usr/lib /mnt/lib`, because during early system boot (initrd stage) the main partition will be mounted first to `/new_root`. Would the symlink be absolute, you would get the above-mentioned error during early boot.

Comment: Small hint: When using systemrescuecd, I often just iterate over proc/sys/dev (for path in proc sys dev ; do mount -obind /$path /mnt/$path ; done) before doing the chroot. However if you're using the arch install iso, much easier to just run the provided arch-chroot executable as it does everything for you. Its in the arch-install-scripts package if someone wants to poke around. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to run 32-bit application on a 64 bit operating system as mentioned by user1334609, so I needed to install 32-bit compatibility libraries. I'm on Ubuntu, so I did this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
apt install libc6-i386
```

It worked and my elf file was able to find ld-linux. It then failed loading some libs, which I troubleshooted one by one.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I recently encountered the same error on some `gcc`-compiled files:

```bash
~/c_trials $ ./bb05
-bash: ./bb05: cannot execute: required file not found
```

I thought I had lost my mind... but then recalled:

> ***I had recently moved this file (and the folder w/ all the files) **from** a Raspberry Pi 3 running `bullseye` **to** a Raspberry Pi 5 running `bookworm`***.

After re-compiling on the RPi 5, everything was copacetic:

```bash
~/c_trials $ gcc -o bb05 bb05.c
~/c_trials $ ./bb05
blah, blah, blah
```

#### Lessons learned:

1. All ARM machines are **not** created equal.
2. Differences in `glibc` version may upset your apple cart.
3. Error messages can be very misleading.